# Auto Increment for each Duplicate Value in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I am using Oracle Database Integrator (ODI) to create an interface for a new table.

What I am trying to do is to incrementally increase a number for each duplicate appearance of a value in another column. For example, for the table:

```
Person_ID  | ...
32         | ...
45         | ...
32         | ...
67         | ...
45         | ...
45         | ...
```

The interface would output the following in the target table:

```
Person_ID | Sequence_Number | ...  
32        |       1         | ...
45        |       1         | ...
32        |       2         | ...
67        |       1         | ...
45        |       2         | ...
45        |       3         | ...
```

I've tried to do this by entering various SQL queries into the Implementation text editor in Mapping Properties, but it seems like I cannot actually make it incrementally increase.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

you can use `row_number()`, or `rank()` with `over(partition by personId order by personId)`

```
select personId,
       row_number() over(partition by personId order by personId) Sequence_Number
from your_table
```

**Edit:** if you want the result sorted as exactly like the desired output you mentioned, you need to do `order by rownum` twice to guarantee the desired sort:

```
select personId,
       row_number() over(partition by personId order by rownum) Sequence_Number
from your_table
order by rownum
```

Below is a check for above queries:

---

```
SQL> create table your_table (personId int);

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2      into your_table values(32)
  3      into your_table values(45)
  4      into your_table values(32)
  5      into your_table values(67)
  6      into your_table values(45)
  7      into your_table values(45)
  8      select * from dual;

6 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select personId,
  2         row_number() over(partition by personId order by rownum) Sequence_Number
  3  from your_table;

  PERSONID SEQUENCE_NUMBER
---------- ---------------
        32               1
        32               2
        45               1
        45               2
        45               3
        67               1

6 rows selected.

SQL> select personId,
  2         row_number() over(partition by personId order by rownum) Sequence_Number
  3  from your_table
  4  order by rownum;

  PERSONID SEQUENCE_NUMBER
---------- ---------------
        32               1
        45               1
        32               2
        67               1
        45               2
        45               3

6 rows selected.

SQL> drop table your_table;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

Comment: You can simply do `ORDER BY NULL` or `ORDER BY rownum` in this case - and I would use `ROW_NUMBER()` over `RANK()` in case there's another column the OP wants to use for ordering.

Comment: @DavidFaber , only `order by rownum` one time, does not guarantee the desired sort, the OP needs to does that order `twice` one in `over()` part and the other at the end of query, however thanks for your comment, answer edited.

Comment: Right, I was suggesting `ORDER BY rownum` only to have *something* in the required `ORDER BY` clause. I don't know if there is a desired sort on the part of the OP or not.

Comment: me too I've not exactly understood the OP's scenario, your comment was very useful thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! the question was more related to doing this in ODI and referencing a temporary table. I have partially figured this out using a counter but have given up on this.